# Perform JOIN in tables django

Tags: python, django

Perform JOIN on in django fetching related date in reverse relationship.
There are three models.

Following is code for models

```js
class Question(models.Model):
 title = models.CharField(max_length=255 )
 description = models.TextField(max_length=300)
  

class Quiz(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=225,blank=False )
 quiz_type =models.IntegerField(choices=QUIZ_TYPE,default=0)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField( Question, through='QuestionQuiz', related_name="quiz_question") 
 categories= models.ManyToManyField(Category,through='CategoryQuiz',related_name='quiz_category')  
 

class QuestionQuiz(models.Model):
 quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 question = models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
 correct =models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
    incorrect= models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3) 

 class Meta:
  unique_together = ('quiz','question')
```

In this the questions are added to the quiz using model Question Quiz.

Here , QuizQuestion has foreign key relationship with the question. I need to fetch all from question JOIN and records from QuestionQuiz with a particular quiz_id.

Suppose quiz_id =3 
Then I will fetch all questions with correct and incorrect. if that quiz id is added to the question then it will display correct incorrect else these would be blank.

`question_id | title|description|correct|incorrect|quesquizid

          1  | Q1   |Q1desc     |2      |   -2    |   1
          2  | Q2   |Q2desc     |       |         |`

ques_id =1 added to quiz_id=3 .ques_id=2 not added to quiz_id=3.So, correct incorrect are blank.

I tried following but it fetches all question and related quizes scores irrespective of their occurrence in current quiz :

`Question.objects.prefetch_related('questionquiz_set').all()`

The result should be similar to following query

`Select * from  question as qs   LEFT JOIN  questionquiz as qq on (qq.question_id = qs.id AND qq.id=3)`

Please check the result of the query:

[image]

Comment: Your django Question query would just return all Question objects. Your SQL querry would return a single Question related to QuestionQuiz with id = 3. Is that what you want - a single question related to specific QuestionQuiz?

Comment: @AzamatGalimzhanov No It would result all questions with correct and incorrect. Please check the attached image which displays result of the query execution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think prefetch_related along with Prefetch may get you the desired result.

`q = Question.objects.prefetch_related(
                Prefetch('questionquiz_set', queryset=QuestionQuiz.objects.filter(quiz=3))
            )
        print(q)`

This may retrieve all related data along with null if exist.